# js картинка не показывает

Tags: javascript

```js
var prev = document.querySelector('.owl-prev');
prev.innerHTML = '<img src="../img/icons8-back-filled-50.png" alt="стрелка лево">';
```

когда gulp запускаю картинка видна, а когда двойным кликом мыши нажимаю на index.html и документ отображается в браузере картинку не видно

ПОЧЕМУ ТАК ?

Comment: <img src="../img/icons8-back-filled-50 После названия наверное нужно указать формат изображения «.jpg» или в чем у тебя там, может .png

Comment: @Vladimir Rodichev не помогло

Comment: @Vladimir Rodichev когда gulp запускаю картинка видна, а когда двойным кликом мыши нажимаю на index.html картинки не видно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не надо **../** использовать. Положение index.html, в случае открытия его с локального диска, определяет корень сайта. В целях безопасности, браузер не пустит выше корня.
Вот если, например, у Вас структура:

```
-css
  --index.css
-images
  --image1.png
```

и Вы в css указали:

```
background-image: url('../images/image1.png');
```

Тогда - пожалуйста.